# Replace one word of a string if that word is within a specific number of words of another word

Tags: python, regex, conditional-statements

I have a text column within a dataframe called 'DESCRIPTION'. I need to find all instances where the word "tile" or "tiles" is within 6 words of the word "roof" and then change just the word "tile/s" to "rooftiles".  I need to do the same for "floor" and "tiles" (change "tiles" to "floortiles"). This will help distinguish what building trade we are looking at when certain words are used in conjunction with other words.

To show what I mean, an example of the data and my latest incorrect try is:

```
s1=pd.Series(["After the storm the roof was damaged and some of the tiles are missing"])
s2=pd.Series(["I dropped the saw and it fell on the floor and damaged some of the tiles"])
s3=pd.Series(["the roof was leaking and when I checked I saw that some of the tiles were cracked"])
df=pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2),  list(s3)],  columns =  ["DESCRIPTION"])
df
```

The solution I am after should look something like this (in a dataframe format):

```
1.After the storm the roof was damaged and some of the rooftiles are missing      
2.I dropped the saw and it fell on the floor and damaged some of the floortiles
3.the roof was leaking and when I checked I saw that some of the tiles were cracked
```

here I tried to match using a REGEX pattern to replace the word "tiles" but it is completely wrong... is there even a way to do what I am trying to do? I am new to Python...

```
regex=r"(roof)\b\s+([^\s]+\s+){0,6}\b(.*tiles)"
replacedString=re.sub(regex, r"(roof)\b\s+([^\s]+\s+){0,6}\b(.*rooftiles)", df['DESCRIPTION'])
```

## UPDATE: SOLUTION

Thanks for all the help! I managed to get it working using Jan's code with a few additions/tweaks. Final working code is below (using real, not example, file and data):

```
claims_file = pd.read_csv(project_path + claims_filename) # Read input file
claims_file["LOSS_DESCRIPTION"] = claims_file["LOSS_DESCRIPTION"].fillna('NA') #get rid of encoding errors generated because some text was just 'NA' and it was read in as NaN
#create the REGEX    
rx =  re.compile(r'''
        (                      # outer group
            \b(floor|roof)     # floor or roof
            (?:\W+\w+){0,6}\s* # any six "words"
        )
        \b(tiles?)\b           # tile or tiles
        ''', re.VERBOSE)

#create the reverse REGEX
rx2 =  re.compile(r'''
        (                      # outer group
            \b(tiles?)     # tile or tiles
            (?:\W+\w+){0,6}\s* # any six "words"
        )
        \b(floor|roof)\b           # roof or floor
        ''', re.VERBOSE)
#apply it to every row of Loss Description:
claims_file["LOSS_DESCRIPTION"] = claims_file["LOSS_DESCRIPTION"].apply(lambda x: rx.sub(r'\1\2\3', x)) 

#apply the reverse regex:
claims_file["LOSS_DESCRIPTION"] = claims_file["LOSS_DESCRIPTION"].apply(lambda x: rx2.sub(r'\3\1\2', x)) 

# Write results into CSV file and check results
claims_file.to_csv(project_path + output_filename, index = False
                       , encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Comment: Can you post what you want as the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a solution with a regular expression here:

```
(                      # outer group
    \b(floor|roof)     # floor or roof
    (?:\W+\w+){1,6}\s* # any six "words"
)
\b(tiles?)\b           # tile or tiles
```

See [**a demo for the regex on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/z5CyKy/1).

---

Afterwards, just combine the captured parts and put them together again with `rx.sub()` and apply this to all items of the `DESCRIPTION` column, so that you end up having the following code:

```
import pandas as pd, re

s1 = pd.Series(["After the storm the roof was damaged and some of the tiles are missing"])
s2 = pd.Series(["I dropped the saw and it fell on the floor and damaged some of the tiles"])
s3 = pd.Series(["the roof was leaking and when I checked I saw that some of the tiles were cracked"])

df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2),  list(s3)],  columns =  ["DESCRIPTION"])

rx = re.compile(r'''
            (                      # outer group
                \b(floor|roof)     # floor or roof
                (?:\W+\w+){1,6}\s* # any six "words"
            )
            \b(tiles?)\b           # tile or tiles
            ''', re.VERBOSE)

# apply it to every row of "DESCRIPTION"
df["DESCRIPTION"] = df["DESCRIPTION"].apply(lambda x: rx.sub(r'\1\2\3', x))
print(df["DESCRIPTION"])
```

---

Please note though that your original question was not quite clear: this solution will only find `tile` or `tiles` *after* `roof`, meaning a sentence like `Can you give me the tile for the roof, please?` won't be matched (although the word `tile` is within the range of six words from `roof`, that is).

Comment: Thanks Jan! This worked perfectly! I see what you mean about the REGEX not working both ways... I found a way around this by simply running the code twice...not sure if this is the best way to go about it but It looks like it worked! I have posted the final code I used as an update

Answer (score 2):

I'll show you a quick and dirty incomplete implementation. You can surely make it more robust and useful. Let's say `s` is one of your descriptions:

```
s = "I dropped the saw and it fell on the roof and damaged roof " +\
    "and some of the tiles"
```

Let's first break it into words (tokenize; you can eliminate punctuation if you want):

```
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
```

Now, select the tokens of interest and sort them alphabetically, but remember their original positions in `s`:

```
my_tokens = sorted((w.lower(), i) for i,w in enumerate(tokens)
                    if w.lower() in ("roof", "tiles"))
#[('roof', 6), ('roof', 12), ('tiles', 17)]
```

Combine identical tokens and create a dictionary, where the tokens are keys, and lists of their positions are values. Use dictionary comprehension:

```
token_dict = {name: [p0 for _, p0 in pos] 
              for name,pos 
              in itertools.groupby(my_tokens, key=lambda a:a[0])}
#{'roof': [9, 12], 'tiles': [17]}
```

Go through the list of `tiles` positions, if any, and see if there is a `roof` nearby, and if so, change the word:

```
for i in token_dict['tiles']:
    for j in token_dict['roof']:
        if abs(i-j) <= 6: 
            tokens[i] = 'rooftiles'
```

Finally, put the words together again:

```
' '.join(tokens)
#'I dropped the saw and it fell on the roof and damaged roof '+\
#' and some of the rooftiles'
```

Comment: Thanks DYZ! I got this working on a test set but when I tried to run on my csv file I had a little trouble... I found Jan's solution a little bit easier to implement

Answer (score 1):

I can generalize this to more substrings than "roof" and "floor" but this seems a simpler code:

```
for idx,r in enumerate(df.loc[:,'DESCRIPTION']):
    if "roof" in r and "tile" in r:
        fill=r[r.find("roof")+4:]
        fill = fill[0:fill.replace(' ','_',7).find(' ')]
        sixWords = fill if fill.find('.') == -1 else ''
        df.loc[idx,'DESCRIPTION'] = r.replace(sixWords,sixWords.replace("tile", "rooftile"))
    elif "floor" in r and "tile" in r:
        fill=r[r.find("floor")+5:]
        fill = fill[0:fill.replace(' ','_',7).find(' ')]
        sixWords = fill if fill.find('.') == -1 else ''
        df.loc[idx,'DESCRIPTION'] = r.replace(sixWords,sixWords.replace("tile", "floortile"))
```

Note that this also includes a check for a fullstop("."). You can remove it by removing the `sixWords` variable and replacing it with `fill`

Comment: Thankyou for your help! however I get an error with this code : TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

The major problem you have is the .* in front of tiles in your regex. That makes it so that any number of any characters can go there and still match. The \b's are unnecessary, since they are at boundaries between whitespace and non-whitespace anyway. And the grouping ()'s weren't being used either, so I removed them.

r"(roof\s+[^\s]+\s+){0,6}tiles" will match only roof within 6 "words" (groups of non-whitespace characters separated by whitespace) of tiles. To replace it, take all but the last 5 characters of the matched string from the regex, add "rooftiles", then substitute the matched string with the updated string. Or, you could group everything but the tiles with () in the regex, then replace that group with itself plus "roof". You can't use re.sub for something this complex because it will replace the entire match from roof to tiles, not just the word tiles.